# ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE can't execute camera function

Tags: android

I'm using `Galaxy S4` and `Galaxy J3` for testing my app and clicking a button triggers camera function.

When my app calls camera function with **intent(ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)**

- **Galaxy J3** works fine no matter how many time I call the camera
  function.
- **Galaxy S4**...it works fine when I call the camera for the first time. 
  But the problem is that if I click the button again, the camera app
  pops up a dialog and it says it can't execute camera app..

I don't think that it's because my codes has an error. 
Because.. everything is OK on my galaxy j3

Kindly assist me what might be the possible issue.

Comment: please add android os version on both devices

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use this in your java file

```
 Intent cameraIntent=new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

for viewing captured image and save automatically

```
 pic=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"filename" + ".jpg");
 cameraIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, picUri);

 cameraIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
 startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, PHOTO);
```

also add permission in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```